# Add additional parameters to ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have created a method which will execute an `.exe` file as Admin.
I want to use the same method for two different `.exe` file, but `.exe` files look different from each other. So, they need different number of parameters.
The method is like below:

```
public static int RunProcessAsAdmin(string exeName, string parameters)
{
    try {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = CurrentDirectory;
        startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, exeName);
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";

        if (parameters.Contains("myValue")) {
            startInfo.Arguments = parameters + "otherParam1" + "otherParam2";
        } else {
            startInfo.Arguments = parameters;
        }
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

        Process process = process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        return process.ExitCode;
    } 

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        WriteLog(ex);
        return ErrorReturnInteger;
    }
}
```

Here `if (parameters.Contains("myValue"))` i detect somehow which `.exe` file is being executed. But, adding parameters like this does not work properly: `startInfo.Arguments = parameters + "otherParam1" + "otherParam2";`

Is it possible to add additional parameters like this?

Comment: Remember to add spaces inbetween the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

`ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` is just a string so put a space between each argument:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "argument1 argument2";
```

**Update:**

So change:

```
startInfo.Arguments = parameters + "otherParam1" + "otherParam2";
```

to this *(only if you will change `"otherParam1"` and `"otherParam2"` to variables)*:

```
startInfo.Arguments = parameters + " " + "otherParam1" + " " + "otherParam2";
```

and if you aren't going to change `"otherParam1"` and `"otherParam2"` to variables then use:

```
startInfo.Arguments = parameters + " " + "otherParam1 otherParam2";
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments is a string so you could use `string.Format`:

```
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", parameters, otherParam1, otherParam2);
```